# Wistia player -- How to play a video as HTML5 in Firefox?

Tags: html, flash, firefox, video, wistia

I am using Wistia for video hosting and the wistia player for playing the video in my website. I need to detect video player events like 'pause' and 'end' and play another video based on some criteria.

The following code changes the video being played when the video is paused. This code works perfectly on Chrome and Safari. But in Firefox (Ver 29), the video is played through the flash plugin and the video player events like 'pause', 'end' are not generated.

```
  <script>
  var firstVideoId = "993554ba94",
  var secondVideoId = "9dc0dc7d3a";

firstVideo = Wistia.embed( firstVideoId , {
  container: "video_container",
  playerPreference: "html5"
});
firstVideo.bind('pause',function(){
        // Play next video.   
    changeVideo();
});
firstVideo.play();

function changeVideo() {
    // Remove first video and play the second.
    firstVideo.remove();
    secondVideo = Wistia.embed( secondVideoId , {
    container: "video_container",
playerPreference: "html5",
    autoPlay: true
  });
   secondVideo.bind('pause',function() {
        changeBack();
    });
}

function changeBack() {
           // Remove second video and play the first
    secondVideo.remove();
    firstVideo = Wistia.embed( firstVideoId , {
        container: "video_container",
        playerPreference: "html5",
        autoPlay: true
    });
    firstVideo.bind('pause',function() {
        changeVideo();
    });
    firstVideo.play();
}
  </script>
```

Here are my questions:

1. How to play the video as HTML5 in Firefox (playerPreference is not helping).
2. Is there a way to capture the events when the flash plugin is used to play the video.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Firefox 31. Did you find the cause of this?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this on firefox, having similar issues?

Comment: I have the same issue. Haven't found a solution yet.